# Why does simply declaring (not initialising) implicit variables produce a ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript

Why does `var/let/const = x` not produce a ReferenceError

```js
var x;
```

but just `x` does?

```js
x;
```

I understand `x` to be an implicit variable. I thought the implicit variable would've declared variable `x` which returns `undefined`, like `var/let/const x`

Comment: Because javascript 'use strict' forces variables to be declared before they are referenced.  `var x` **is** the declaration

Comment: you need to declare variables to define their scope

Comment: @Taplar Does that imply implicit variables can't be declared before they're referenced unless you initialise them (with something like `x = 5`?).

Comment: `x = 5` on it's own would be an assignment before an explicit declaration.  strict mode forces you to explicitly declare your variables

Comment: @Taplar So essentially `var x` is an assignment. (Is it assigning `undefined` to x?). But just `x` doesn't also assign `undefined` to `x`?

Comment: `var x;` is a declaration.  `var x = 5;` is a declaration and assignment.  `x = 5` is an assignment, and potential **implicit** declaration if it was not previously declared.

Comment: @Taplar Got you. I understand in strict mode variables have to be declared before they're referenced (apart from `var`? At least `node.js` you can reference it before it's declared and assigned and it won't give a ReferenceError - the var variable will just return `undefined`). I also get `x = 5` is an assignment and potential implicit declaration. I just want confirmed that implicit variables are sort of unique in their inability to be declared without also being initialised, like `var x`.

Comment: Prior to strict mode, implicit declaration would not cause a compilation error.  Which is why you are not seeing the error in node.  Presumably your node is not running in strict mode.  If you added `"use strict;"` (quotes included) to the start of your node script, I would expect it to start erroring if you performed the same type of initialization in there.

Comment: @Taplar I think what I'm trying to say, and have confirmed, is `let x` declares (therefore you can reference it). `x` doesn't declare (because you can't reference it). `x` can only be declared when you successfully initialise it at the same time too (`x = 5;`)

Comment: `x` does declare, if it is not already declared.  But it does so **implicitly**.  Strict mode forces **explicit** declarations.  That's the primary point.

Comment: @Taplar Okay got you!

Comment: @Taplar this then suggests that `x = 5` is declaring explicitly? Otherwise how does this work?

Comment: No, explicit declarations include `var`/`let`/`const` in the declaration.

Comment: @Taplar Well then how do you account for the fact that `x` is an implicit declaration, and that's why it produces a ReferenceError. And `x = 5` seem to also be an an implicit declaration, and produces no error?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7b3x59r4/  Are you saying you don't see this console error?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7b3x59r4/1/ <= so given this error, `x;` on its own apparently is not even an implicit declaration.

Comment: @Taplar Sorry `x = 5` is producing an error, I don't know why I thought it wasn't. Thanks for your explanation, I do get it now.